# How to use Flask get client's port?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to build a simple torrent-tracker with Flask, but I meet a problem.

If client in **NAPT** network, the port, which included in request is incorrect. I want to get client connect port with Flask (In PHP like this function: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']`).

How to get client port with Flask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it from `request.environ`

```
request.environ.get('REMOTE_PORT')
```

Answer (score 3):

If Flask is behind a reverse proxy,

```
request.environ.get('REMOTE_PORT')
```

will **not** give you what you want, you are going to get the port
used by the reverse proxy.

If using Nginx, add this **bold** line to your config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        proxy_pass ...;
        proxy_set_header WHATEVER $remote_port;
    } 
}
```

Then you can get the client port with :

```
request.headers.get('WHATEVER')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `print(request.environ)` to see its keys.
For example you can get it by `origin = request.environ.get('HTTP_ORIGIN')  port = origin.split(":")[-1]`