# how to implement flask redirect decorator

Tags: flask, python-decorators, flask-restful, flask-login

I have a flask application instance running on port 80 and another instance of same app on port 8080. I want all the users to use port 80 for all the urls except for one url named `/parallel_url`. So when they visit `https://server:80/parallel_url` it redirects to `https://server:8080/parallel_url`. I also don't want users to be able to visit any other url (excluding `/parallel_url`) on port 8080 and i want them to be redirected to post 80
so if they visit `https://server:8080/*` it needs to redirect to `https://server:80/*`

I am planning to write a decorator which sees if the current url is anything other than `/parallel_url` and redirect it to the 80. So if a user is visiting this in port 8080 they need to get redirected to 80

```py
def parallel_redirect(func):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper():
        """
           What to do here to redirect to 80
        """
        if request.url_rule == "/parallel_url":
            value = func()
        return value
    return wrapper

@mod.route('/parallel_url')
@parallel_redirect
@login_required
def parallel_url():
    template = tpl_env.get_template('my_index.html')
    x = "some data from db"
    y = "some other data from db"
    return template.render(x=x,y=y)
```

update:
I found an a variable which tells me what port i am on. please refer the code below

```py
def parallel_redirect(func):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper():
        if os.environ.curr_port == 8080:
            if request.url_rule != "/parallel_url":
               # code to redirect to "https://server:80/"+request.url_rule
        elif os.environ.curr_port == 80:
            if request.url_rule == "/parallel_url":
               # code to redirect to "https://server:8080/"+request.url_rule
        else:
             value = func()

        return value
    return wrapper

@mod.route('/parallel_url')
@parallel_redirect
@login_required
def parallel_url():
    template = tpl_env.get_template('my_index.html')
    x = "some data from db"
    y = "some other data from db"
    return template.render(x=x,y=y)
```

Comment: why was this question voted down, a vote down should come with a comment, feedback. It would help the OP to frame question better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just catch all possible combinations and use the `redirect` function to call the other server. You just need the current port from the request, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34787231/5015356)

```py
from flask import redirect

def parallel_redirect(func):
  @functools.wraps(func):
    request_port = request.environ.get('REMOTE_PORT')
    if request.url_rule == "/parallel_url":
      if request_port == 80:
        # /parallel_url, but on port 80, redirect
        return redirect("https://...:8080/parallel_url", code=302)
      else:
        return func()
    elif request_port == 8080:
      # not /parallel_url, but on port 8080, also redirect
      return redirect("https://...:80" + request.url_rule, code=302)
    # finally, not /parallel_url, and on port 80, so we're all good
    return func()
```